# Multiline styled text within a button element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, button

I am trying to put 2 buttons on a web page, one floated to the left and the other to the right.  Both command buttons have multiline styled text within them.  Below is my latest attempt.  It seems to work on in Firefox, but not even close in IE 8.  Any ideas how I can get this to work in both environments?  thanks.

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-color: green;
}

.idxQuestion {
    font-size: 36;
    text-align: center;
}

.idxButtons {
    margin-top:60px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:350px;
}

.buttonchoice1,.buttonchoice2
           {
    text-align: center;
    background:white;
    padding: 5px;
}

.buttonchoice1 {
    float:left; 
    border:5px solid red;
}

.buttonchoice2 {
    float:right;
    border:5px solid blue;
}   

.spanchoice1 {
    font-size: 30px;             
}

.spanchoice2 {
    font-size: 10px;             
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="idxQuestion">
    <h1>Big Question?</h1>
</div>
<div class="idxButtons">
    <h:button class="buttonchoice1" onclick="option1?faces-redirect=true" >
        <h:outputText escape=false>
            <span class="spanchoice1">No</span><br />  
            <span class="spanchoice2">additional info 1</span> 
        </h:outputText>
    </h:button> 

    <h:button class="buttonchoice2" onclick="option2?faces-redirect=true" >
        <h:outputText>
            <span class="spanchoice1">Yes</span><br />  
            <span class="spanchoice2">additional info 2</span> 
        </h:outputText>
    </h:button> 

</div>
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/MF23L/

Comment: Where is the "h" tag coming from?

Comment: I guess he's pasting ASP.NET code directly to html page..and as we know how **IE** is, it is rendering incorrectly, just remove all `h:` from your markup

Comment: For sometime I thought i am the only one in CSS who doesnt know `H` tag. hehe

Comment: @Mr_Green CSS 3 Reloaded..LOL

Comment: Sorry, I am using JSF and that is where the h: is coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this piece of code:

```
<div class="idxButtons">
    <button class="buttonchoice1" onclick="option1?faces-redirect=true">
        <outputText escape=false>
           <span class="spanchoice1">No</span><br />  
           <span class="spanchoice2">additional info 1</span> 
        </outputText>
     </button>
    <button class="buttonchoice2" onclick="option2?faces-redirect=true">
        <outputText>
           <span class="spanchoice1">Yes</span><br />  
           <span class="spanchoice2">additional info 2</span> 
        </outputText>
     </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I just realized if I float the button to the left or right, the button is floated out or normal flow, but not the outputText, so the text is outside the button.

Answer (score 0):

IE isn't recognizing your h:button tag, which you've applied a "buttonchoice1" class to and is the basis of your layout.  If you were to wrap those "h:button"s with a div (for example), and move the class from the h:button to the new containing div, it should work.  Like this:

```
<div class="idxButtons">
    <div class="buttonchoice1">
        <h:button onclick="option1?faces-redirect=true" >
        <h:outputText escape=false>
        <span class="spanchoice1">No</span><br />  
        <span class="spanchoice2">additional info 1</span> 
        </h:outputText>
        </h:button> 
    </div>
....
```

Comment: Yes, removing the h: fixed it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make images and use `<input type="image" alt="No, additional info 1" src="..." />` so it would look the same? I am don't think `button` is supposed to be fancy.